# selenium save div background-image as file

Tags: javascript, selenium, web-crawler

Does anyone know how to save a div background-image as an image file with selenium (or other crawler technology).

The code of the div is as follows (sorry I have to hide part of the link):

```
<div class="chapter" id="BookImage" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://xxxxx/aaaa/book_chapter_image?chapter_id=101887270&amp;area_width=592&amp;font_size=27&amp;image_code=OnY9InjKKKJJJPKZDfMZjb;);">
                <img width="100%" id="realBookImage" src="https://xxxxx/images/empty.gif" style="pointer-events: none; height: 8869px; width: 100%;">
            </div>
```

Though there is "url" but it seems the url is one-time so I cannot get the image from server side.

But in dev mode of Chrome I can see the image in "Sources" tab. I just wonder if there is any method to retrieve the image and save it as a file.

Please enlighten me if you have any idea. Thanks a lot!

Comment: So you tried parsing out the URL from the background image and navigating to that URL and it didn't work?

Comment: @JeffC Yes. Navigating to that URL returns me another image.

Comment: The wrong image or ? Post a link to the site.

Comment: Sorry the link needs to login some paid account. I decide to use a compromised solution to screenshot that div. Thanks a lot anyway! @JeffC